# Discord.py: How to get info from Codeforces.com

Tags: discord.py

I am coding a discord bot in discord.py, and i want to be able to make a bot that will alert the members of a discord server, 24 hours before a contest starts. How would i pull info from the website? [Image of Data, I want the highlighted data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oe5Nw.png)

I am a noob at javascript, and i have tried and failed to pull data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want you can go through requests and find the endpoint they use to get the time remaining

or quick and dirty:

```py
import requests, time

pinged = False

r = requests.get("https://codeforces.com/contests/1882", headers = {"user-agent":"Samsung Smart Fridge/420.69"})

h, m, s = r.text.split('class="countdown" noRedirection="true">')[1].split("</div>")[0].split(":")

# 10:04:00

# h, m, s = 10, 04, 00

while pinged == False:
 if (int(h) <= 24):
  # do the pinging thing
  pinged = True # or some other way of making it not ping
 time.sleep((int(h)-24)*3600) # adjust if you need it to ping exactly 24h before, this will be up to 59m59s late
```